# android startActivity sdk23 open image crash

Tags: android, android-activity

```
 findViewById(R.id.openImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "4.jpg");
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            if (f.exists()) {
                Uri uri =  Uri.fromFile(f);
                i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

↑When I click the button, it should start an activity that **opens an image**.However it just **crashed without throwing any error**, as the following android monitor shows.

> 08-15 16:48:33.715 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
>   08-15 16:48:33.821 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
>   08-15 16:48:33.821 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>   08-15 16:48:33.821 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
>   08-15 16:48:33.821 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
>   08-15 16:48:33.857 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa8232400: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
>   08-15 16:48:33.883 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8232400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa820b0b0)
>   08-15 16:48:34.073 24956-24994/com.example.administrator.readcontact D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa8232400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa820b0b0)
>   08-15 16:52:23.554 24956-24965/com.example.administrator.readcontact I/zygote: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 11.170ms for cause ObjectsAllocated

```
↑ There isn't any error shown in the android monitor.

---

The file path of the image is  **4.jpg** under **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**, namely "/sdcard/4.jpg".

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

↑ I have added this code

---

```
int ok1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (ok1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_READ);
        }
```

↑I have got the permission to read the external storage.

---

I can be sure that:

- the **file path is right**, because when I tried opening the file path("/sdcard/4.jpg") in an **imageView** it **succeeded**.
- I have **got the permission** to read the external storage.I have clicked "yes" when the os asked me if I allowed the operation.
- **sdk version is 26**.So I think the app should get the permission when reading "/sdcard/4.jpg"

Comment: you want to view this file in native gallery app right ?

Comment: Yes. I saw a tutorial open an image easily in the system with lower sdk version.But I'm running it on sdk26...

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine slight changes. Hope it will be useful for you.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "4.jpg");
            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```